# VueJS - Loading data with axios - Data empty

Tags: api, vue.js, axios

I have an VueJS project and my API, both in local.
I have a problem when i use Axios, data didnt load.

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Array, got Object

*So, it's logic and i understand it, when the page load, "data" is empty and "slice()" function cant be execute on an empty array.*

**How can i correct it ?**

I use "**Vuestic**" template, and the original file is [this one](https://github.com/epicmaxco/vuestic-admin/blob/master/src/components/data-tables/scenarios/DataTableSortingPagination.vue)

They dont use axios, but directly a Json file, so for them "users" is already defined for the "slice()" function.

I tried tu use a "**v-if**" on the table, but didnt worked

My code :

```
import axios from 'axios';

var tokenStorage = localStorage.getItem('token')
var data = [];
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      data: data.slice(),
      title: 'Les prochaines dates',
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
        axios
    .get('https://api.test/api/dates',
    {
      headers: {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + tokenStorage 
      }
    })
        .then(response => (this.data = response))
    },
```

My API response :

it's "**dates**" on the left, the second request is the "**Preflight Request**"  (*Status Code: 204 No Content*), i dont know if that can be the reason of my problem
[image]

Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, the server needs to release the authorization request header

Answer (score 0):

You could use `data.json()` to convert your response to an appropriate format.

I personally use the js build in fetch library but that should work similar in axios if you need to stick with it. You just need to add your authentication.

```js
    data () {
        return {
            response: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async doRequest () {
            const response = await fetch('https://api.test/api/dates')
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data, data.slice()); // <-- These are the same
            this.response = data.slice();
        }
    },
    created () {
        this.doRequest()
    }
```